# How are film festivals like BQFF able to bypass CBFC certification?

Tags: content-rating, censorship

I have heard about film festivals like [BQFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_Queer_Film_Festival), etc. where they show films which have even failed to clear CBFC (Central Board of Film Certification)'s
certification or few might not even applied for it.

How can a film festival be able to bypass CBFC certification? Do film festivals have a different rule in India for clearance than released films?

Comment: I guess it comes down to the definition of "public exhibition". Films (generally) only require a certificate if they are to be distributed to the general public. If it's a "private event", then no such certification is *required*. AFAIK.

Comment: @Paulie_D Maybe you can elaborate it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is described in detail [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:o4TuGChH-FgJ:https://www.thehindu.com/entertainment/movies/certificate-policy-raises-questions/article20461093.ece&hl=en&gl=uk). In short, films that are intended for festival release can bypass the normal censor process by [applying for an exemption](https://mib.gov.in/codesguidelinespolicies/policy-certification-films-film-festivals).

> As per the policy for Certification of Films for Film Festivals, a
> copy of which is available with The Hindu , the process of clearing a
> film does not mandate that the film be watched before a decision is
> made.
>
> Since 2016, uncensored films can be screened at the festival, on the
> condition that they receive an exemption certificate from the
> Ministry.
>
> The applications for exemption certificates are processed by the Joint
> Secretary of the Ministry.
>
> <sub><sup>[IFFI row: Certificate policy of I&B ministry raises questions](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:o4TuGChH-FgJ:https://www.thehindu.com/entertainment/movies/certificate-policy-raises-questions/article20461093.ece&hl=en&gl=uk)</sup></sub>

Note that this isn't a *blanket* exemption. Rules still apply regarding moral decency. Having the name of a goddess referred to as "sexy" was sufficient to get one film barred in 2017.

> The policy states that the director of the festival has to send in six
> documents: a list of films to be screened, synopsis of each of the
> films, composition of the preview committee, report of the preview
> committee certifying that the films have been recommended for
> exhibition at the festival, a certificate from the director of the
> festival to the effect that the screening of such films would be
> limited to delegates and a certificate from the director of festival
> to the effect that the festival is non-commercial in nature.
>
> The same process was followed in the present case. The application for
> exemption certificate for Sexy Durga was rejected on 19th September by
> the Ministry when the film was shortlisted among 168 films to be
> screened at Jio MAMI Mumbai Film Festival with Star 2017.

Showing a film that has been barred (or not sought exemption) would still be illegal.